# Display full data from table StudentRegistration to datagridview in Form1 based on ID in texbox,Form2

Tags: c#, database, winforms

I'm struggling with displaying the full data from my table StudentRegistration in a datagridview which is in Form2 based on the ID input in textboxHiddenRFID  from Form1.My problem is that I want to check if the ID that was inputted in textboxHiddenRFID matches the SN(which is a PK in StudentRegistration)in the table and the data matching that SN to be displayed in the datagridview in Form2.Since I am using an RFID reader,I use textboxHiddenRFID  to read the NFC's tag SN and here I will have a break of 3 sec after the NFC tag was read and then again the same operation.Can anyone help me with some examples how to connect the datagridview with the textboxHiddenRFID ?I have tried other examples,but without any luck.This is my code so far:

```
MessageBox.Show("The connection with the card reader was established succesfully!You may now scan NFC cards...");//Form1

try 
{ 
    textBoxHiddenRFID.Focus();
    string connString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\User\source\repos\VIAUniversityCollegeAttendanceApp\VIAUniversityCollegeAttendanceApp\DatabaseAttendanceStudents.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString);
    string strq = "SELECT count (*) from StudentRegistration where SN like" + textBoxHiddenRFID.Text +" ";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strq, con);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (dr.Read())
    {
        int count = (int)dr[0];
        if(count>0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Student already registered in the database"+ msgerror.Text.Trim());
            msgerror.Visible = true;


        }
    }
}
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)//Form2
{
    if(e.ColumnIndex==-1)
    {
        try
        {
            StartUp s2 = new StartUp();
            s2.dgrv = dataGridViewAttendanceList.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            s2.Show();
        }
        catch(Exception er)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(er.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
}  
public AttendanceList()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    InitializePicker();
    dataGridViewAttendanceList.Rows.Add(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
}
```

Comment: If someone types _1;drop table StudentRegistration; --_ you will have a bigger problem to deal. Use parameters

Comment: Sure,using parameters is not a problem for me and I will do so,I've just posted the code so that you guys can make an opinion about what method I have approached and what method I could use for what I need. :)

Comment: SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); ... but you arent doing anything with the data that you get back from your reader..

Comment: @BugFinder SqlDataReader dr=cmd.ExecuteReader(),yes,I know because I don't know if I should do it here or in From2 or if what I wrote in my code here so far is correct.

Comment: Your question is too much unclear. Is this code all in the so called _Form1_ class? Is the Form2 the form named _Startup_?. How do you have filled the dataGridView1? And what is _dataGridViewAttendanceList_?

Comment: @Steve This is not the entire code,it is the code for the scn_btn button,because there all the magic happens.Yes,Form2 is named StartUp but I wanted to give it a generic name and the way I have filed my dataGridView1 is databound.

Comment: @Steve dataGridViewAttendanceList is the name of the datagridview that I'm using to display the data in Form1

Comment: I suggest you to put this code in the Startup form. Just pass the _textBoxHiddenRFID.Text_ to the Startup form through it constructor. Then inside that form just try to load the grid setting its datasource through an SqlDataAdapter filling a DataTable. Or if you want to avoid opening the Startup form if the SN doesn't exist add the code to check in the CellContentClick event handler. By the way, you don't want to count all the records just to test for existance of the SN Use IF EXISTS

Comment: @Steve  Ok,I'll try that!Thank you! :)